# $x+1$ is a factor of $2x^3-5x^2-3x+K$. Find K.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $x+1$ is a factor of $2x^3-5x^2-3x+K$. Find K.

I don't even know where to start with this problem. Thanks in advance to anyone who helps out.

Comment: Hint: you should have: $2(-1)^3-5(-1)^2-3(-1)+K=0$

Comment: **Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ x\!+\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{x\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, f(\color{#c00}x)\equiv f(\color{#c00}{-1})\ $ for polynomial $f(x)\ \ $

Comment: @hamidkamali So $x=-1$. Can you explain why?

Comment: @BleedingCatz If $p(z)$ is a polynomial, $az+b$ is a factor of $p(z)$ if and only if $z=-\frac{b}{a}$ is a root of $p(z)$. i.e $p(-\frac{b}{a})=0$. Since we can write $p(z)=(az+b)Q(z)+cz+d$ where $Q(z)$ is a polynomial. Now, $az+b$ is a factor of $p(z)$ if and only if $cz+d \equiv 0$. i.e $p(-\frac{b}{a})=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or we can use the long division to get:

> $2x^3-5x^2-3x+K=(x+1)(2x^2-7x+4)+(K-4)=0$

Answer (score 7):

Hint: A polynomial $p(x)$ has $x+1$ as a factor iff $p(-1) = 0$.

Comment: Generalized to: Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial, $(x+n)\vert p(x) \iff p(-n) = 0$

Comment: @EliSadoff I'd rather say "specialized from" than "generalized to" :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Touché

Answer (score 0):

If $(x+1)$ is a factor, then by *Remainder theorem.*.. sum of even powered coefficients is equal to that of odd powered ones... a rule to remember.

$$2-3 = -5 +K ;\, \rightarrow ( K=4) $$

(BTW, if $(x+1)$ is  a factor then the sum of all coefficients of a polynomial is zero.)